# How to normalize a matrix of 3-D vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, normalization

I have a 512x512x3 matrix that stores 512x512 there-dimensional vectors. What is the best way to normalize all those vectors, so that my result are 512x512 vectors with length that equals 1?

At the moment I use for loops, but I don't think that is the best way in MATLAB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the vectors are [Euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_%28mathematics%29#Euclidean_vectors), the length of each is the square root of the sum of the squares of its coordinates. To normalize each vector individually so that it has unit length, you need to divide its coordinates by its norm. For that purpose you can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
norm_A = sqrt(sum(A .^ 2, 3)_;   %// Calculate Euclidean length
norm_A(norm_A < eps) == 1;       %// Avoid division by zero
B = bsxfun(@rdivide, A, norm_A); %// Normalize
```

where `A` is your original 3-D vector matrix.

*EDIT: Following Shai's comment, added a fix to avoid possible division by zero for null vectors.*

Comment: At the moment i don't understand how the code works, but it does what I asked for. But i don't need the "avoid division by zero" line. Anybody got an idea why it is not necessary? (I tested it by putting Matrix(1,1,:)=0; just before your code)

Comment: @LibettenRadler Oh, it's rather easy to explain -- [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) is a great function. What it does is apply a [binary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) (in this case [`rdivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/rdivide.html)) element-wise to the two input matrices. When one matrix has fewer dimensions than the other (but it must have the same number of elements along the other dimensions as the larger matrix), it is replicated along the "missing" dimensions`, before performing the operation.

Comment: Thank you for everything! I found out, that if the division by zero happens, the result is NaN and my following code could deal with that. Thats why no Error occured.